# Windows 8 metro app keyboard position change

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

how to change keyboard position change in windows 8 metro application when it is appear on focus on text box it always appear on the bottom of the screen. any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

On Screen Keyboard will appear automatically when a text box got focus, we cannot control it from the app, you can look for events like Showing and Hiding: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/keyboard-events-sample-866ba41c?